# Close a popover div while clicking outside that div

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a popover menu as a `directive` using `angularjs` in my sharepoint 2013 application. This is been used in all the other pages to show a small help window, while clicking a link. Now, I need to close this menu once the user clicks any where else in the screen other than the close button.

I'm using `SharePoint 2013` and `angularjs`.

How can I achieve this ? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any one have idea about this ?